# Ethiopic with dead keys unicode typing

Tags: input, unicode, ms-word, libreoffice, oxygenxml

this is a question I have posed already in two forums for different aspects (keyman and oxygen XML product forums), but I suspect there is a more general issue which I fail to see.

I have Keyman installed on Mac OS X and would like to use it with Word, libreoffice, oxygen or other software to type ethiopic script. However the behavior is quite strange in my understanding.

If I type a combination to obtain a character like 'h+a' I expect to obtain 'ሀ' but I get 'ሀh' or typing b+a to get 'በ' I get instead 'b በ'

In TextEdit for example this works fine and I do not understand why it does so in word and other editors.

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Which keyboard are you using -- one from [this page](http://keyboards.ethiopic.org) perhaps?  Also, does the problem occur with other writing systems such as [IPA](http://www.tavultesoft.com/ipa/)?  If not, then maybe using a different Ethiopic keyboard would help.

Comment: I am using the ethiopic keyboard suggested by Keyman and others which have been made and are daily used by colleagues. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Keyman for Mac OS X is a beta release product. This means that it has known issues and is being made available for testing. So, this is a known bug in the beta release of Keyman for Mac OS X. At the bottom of the [Keyman for Mac OS X home page](http://keyman.com/macosx/) you can see a list of known issues, and the relevant issue is:

> ​Keyman does not detect context correctly in Open Office or LibreOffice or MS Word 2011 14.4.3.

There's not much you can do to solve the problem yourself, bar typing in TextEdit and pasting into other editors (which isn't practical). I am on the Keyman developer team and we are aware of the issue and are working on it.